# Number of ways of choosing positive integers whose square is a constant.

Tags: number-theory

Is there any formula for finding the numer of ways in which 3 positive integers $n_1,n_2,n_3$ can be chosen so that $n_1^2+n_2^2+n_3^2=c$ where $c$ is a constant ? I have seen that if $c=3$ there is only one way (1,1,1). For $c=6$ there are 3 ways-(1,1,2),(1,2,1),(2,1,1). For $c=9$, there are 3 ways- (2,1,2),(2,2,1),(1,2,2). Is it always 3 for higher values of $c$. I am new to this field.

Comment: Try more values of $c$.  You should see that the number varies (and is sometimes $0$).  For sure, $c=14=1^2+2^2+3^2$ has $6$ permutations of $(1,2,3)$.

Comment: This is a hard problem; it was answered by Gauss in his *Disquisitiones Arithmeticae*. The answer involves class numbers (of classes of binary quadratic forms).

Comment: The number of ways is [OEIS sequence A063691](http://oeis.org/A063691) and follow the cross references.